# Forward Euler Pendulum divergence

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have implemented a simple forward euler simulation of the pendulum model:

$$
\ddot{\phi} = -g \sin \phi
$$

[image: Solution]

The solution builds up energy (plot shows $\phi$ w.r.t. time), as it was expected. But after a while it switches from an oscillating behavior to a monotone divergence. Is that expected or a bug in my implementation? If it is expected, why does it happen (coincidentally around $\phi=\pi$)

Comment: It switches from swinging to rotating. Look at a phase portrait.

Comment: Why your solution builds up energy?

Comment: @LutzL: Of course, that should have been obvious!

Comment: @Canis: Well, that is kind of expected from that particular integration method

Comment: Solutions of $\ddot \phi=-g\sin\phi$ don't builds up energy! Probably do you mean something like $\ddot \phi=-g\sin\phi+k \dot\phi$?

Comment: @CanisLupus The Euler method is not symplectic, thus not energy preserving. Studying it in a phase portrait easily demonstrates that it moves to the outside of concentric convex energy levels.

Comment: @CanisLupus This is a pretty neat and classic demonstration of two effects that can be seen in numerical solving of ODEs: 1) careless choice of numerical method for ODE integration doesn't care about conserved quantities; 2) numerical methods doesn't respect the fact that separatrices (and heteroclinic contours with homoclinic loops) divide phase plane into domains and are natural boundaries for these domains (and it's impossible for real trajectory to go from one domain to another).

Comment: Euler is not quite fine unless you use a suitable step at each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the equation describes a swinging pendulum, continuously pumping energy into the swing will steadily increase the maximal angle until it reaches the upwards position. At this point the swinging motion changes into a rotation.

That the numerical method increases the energy can for the Euler method still manageably described. Use $ω =\dot ϕ$ and $E=\frac12ω^2+g(1-\cos ϕ)$. Then the next values are 
\begin{align}
ω_+&=ω-h·g\sinϕ\\
ϕ_+&=ϕ+h·ω\\
E_+&=\frac12(ω-h·g\sinϕ)^2+g(1-\cos(ϕ+h·ω))\\
&=E-h·ωg\sinϕ+\frac12h^2g^2\sin^2ϕ+g\sinϕ·hω+\frac12g\cosϕ·h^2ω^2+O(h^3)\\
&=E+\frac12h^2(g^2\sin^2ϕ+ω^2\cosϕ)+O(h^3)
\end{align}
which on average gives a positive offset from the previous energy.